# Replace a factor in a data frame column into a numeric value in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame df1 such that:

```
group=c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group3","Group 1", "Group 2", "Group3")
year=c("2000","2000","2000", "2015", "2015", "2015")
items=c(12, 10, 15, 5, 10, 7)
df1=data.frame(group, year, items)
```

In the column "group", how do I replace each factor with a numerical value? For example, I want to replace "Group 1" with 0, "Group 2" with 5, and "Group 3" with 3 so it looks like this:

```
  group year items
1     0 2000    12
2     5 2000    10
3     3 2000    15
4     0 2015     5
5     5 2015    10
6     3 2015     7
```

Thanks!

Comment: I changed my example so that the numbers I replace it with are random numbers that I assign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `as.integer`

```
transform(df1, group=as.integer(group))
#   group year items
# 1     1 2000    12
# 2     2 2000    10
# 3     3 2000    15
# 4     1 2015     5
# 5     2 2015    10
# 6     3 2015     7
```

In response to the updated question, you can use a key and index by the integer of your factor

```
key <- c(0, 5, 3)
transform(df1, group=key[as.integer(group)])

#   group year items
# 1     0 2000    12
# 2     5 2000    10
# 3     3 2000    15
# 4     0 2015     5
# 5     5 2015    10
# 6     3 2015     7
```

And as @SimonG says, you can reorder your factor however you want using `factor` and its argument `levels`,

Comment: It may be worth noting that this depends on the ordering of the factor levels. If the levels were `lvls <- c("Group2","Group1","Group 4",...)`, then `as.integer(lvls) = 1 2 3 ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Use an auxiliary named-vector "g" to transform the vector "group":

```
group <- c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group3","Group 1", "Group 2", "Group3")
g <- c(0, 5, 3)
names(g) <- c("Group 1", "Group 2", "Group3")
new_group <- g[group]
```